# Adding a diffent style to the end of a string

Tags: javascript, concatenation, innerhtml

I think this is an easy question, but since I am new to javaScript...

I got an H1 innerHTML using this:

```
var myBeta = "Beta";

var myNode = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

myNode[0].innerHTML = "New List of Materials " + myBeta;
```

How do I make the word "Beta" orange when concatenating the two text strings in the H1?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that their both in the same DOM node (in this case, the same h1) so you can't differentiate between the first and second word. What you have to do is put the word you want in orange in a separate span within the h1. Like this:

```
<h1>
    This is black <span id="orange"> and this is orange</span>
</h1>
```

So your code should look like this:

HTML- empty h1 and span waiting for your JS to fill it

```
<h1><span id="orange"></span></h1>
```

CSS- making the span actually be orange

```
#orange {
    color: orange;
}
```

JS

```
var myBeta = "Beta";
var blackWord = document.getElementsByTageName("h1");
var orangeNode = document.getElementById("orange");

blackWord[0].innerHTML = "New List of Materials";
orangeNode.innerHTML = myBeta;
```

Comment: `getElementByTageName` should be `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: I understand that but in my case I cant touche the H1 element. It is just a string and I don't have access to it.

Comment: Why can't you touch it?

Comment: It is a dynamic page and I only have access to the one file where I can write a bit of javaScript. I tested it adding the 'Beta" part and it worked, now I just need to add the style.

Comment: o. So you can do anything in the JS file, but can't write in the HTML file? What about the CSS file?

Comment: I could potentially call a class from the main css file, but I would rather create a class with javaScript and put on the "Beta".

Comment: I just saw it. It works very well. Thanks for your help also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the Beta string in another element:

```
var myBeta = "Beta";
var wrappedBeta = '<span style="color:orange">' + myBeta + '</span>';
var myNode = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

myNode[0].innerHTML = "New List of Materials " + wrappedBeta;
```

Feel free to extract the style information in an external stylesheet and to change the `span` tag to something more semantically correct (`strong` for example).

Comment: You answer didn't showed in my computer at work. This is brilliant. Thank you